# Adding or removing action parameters in mailing statistics

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, outbound-email

We have enabled outbound email tracking for both email opening and clicking of links as per the documentation. However, we do not require "Profile Update" functionality in newsletter emails.

Mailing statistics provide default action parameters (screenshot below). Is it possible to remove default action parameters from this list. For example: Clicked on atleast one link and Profile Changed etc. As I don't want this functionality.

[image]

I have gone through the documentation of Outbound email and Audience manager, and could not able to find out any guide for customization of these action parameters.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing any documentation or tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to remove the built-in actions.

I would argue that most of those actions are highly relevant when judging the success of your campaign, but you are free to ignore the information if you disagree.